# VS Code not able to find .Net 6 in Ubuntu - Can Not Compile And Run App

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, vscode, and .net 6. When I try to load my app in vs studio, I get this error:

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/one/github/ion/Migration/Tests/Migrator.Tests/Migrator.Tests.csproj'.
/home/one/github/ion/GCPMigration/Tests/AwsMigrator.Tests/Migrator.Tests.csproj
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1232,5): Error: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
```

and in my screen I am not given the option to 'Generate C# assets for Build and Debug':

[image]

I do have .net6 successfully installed:

```
% dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.424 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.405 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I created a global.json file in the root of the project:

```json
 {
    "sdk": {
      "version": "6.0.405"
    }
  }
```

And then I restarted VS code but still no success. How can I make vs code find .net 6?

**UPDATE**: Here is more output:

```
% code --list-extensions --show-versions

jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager@1.1.6
ms-dotnettools.csharp@1.25.4
```

```
% dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.405
 Commit:    27ab36058b

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/

global.json file:
  /home/one/github/ion/Migration/Migrator/global.json

Host:
  Version:      6.0.13
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       1af80ba017

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.424 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.405 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.30 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

**Update 2**:

```
% code -s
[165406:0130/112324.020541:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[165406:0130/112324.020669:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[165406:0130/112324.024558:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[165438:0130/112324.116599:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[165474:0130/112324.239777:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[165543:0130/112324.277406:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[165543:0130/112324.283025:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
Version:          Code 1.73.0 (8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f, 2022-11-01T15:44:09.336Z)
OS Version:       Linux x64 5.4.0-137-generic
CPUs:             AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor (11 x 3393)
Memory (System):  38.26GB (36.34GB free)
Load (avg):       1, 0, 0
VM:               0%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     . --crash-reporter-id 12ef4ab5-5c49-4439-9359-bc412e87bbfd
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                              unavailable_software
                  canvas_oop_rasterization:               disabled_off
                  direct_rendering_display_compositor:    disabled_off_ok
                  gpu_compositing:                        disabled_software
                  multiple_raster_threads:                enabled_on
                  opengl:                                 disabled_off
                  rasterization:                          disabled_software
                  raw_draw:                               disabled_off_ok
                  skia_renderer:                          enabled_on
                  video_decode:                           disabled_software
                  video_encode:                           disabled_software
                  vulkan:                                 disabled_off
                  webgl:                                  unavailable_software
                  webgl2:                                 unavailable_software
                  webgpu:                                 disabled_off

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    0      118  165016  code main
    0       39  165021     zygote
    3      118  165088       gpu-process
    0       39  165022     zygote
    0        0  165024       zygote
    0       39  165079     utility-network-service
    0      313  165116     window (global.json - Migration - Visual Studio Code)
    0      157  165137     shared-process
    0       39  165168       ptyHost
    0        0  165365         /usr/bin/zsh -i
    0        0  165389           sh /usr/bin/code -s
    0       39  165394             /usr/share/code/bin/../code /usr/share/code/bin/../resources/app/out/cli.js --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node -s
    0      118  165406               /usr/share/code/code -s --enable-crashpad
    0       39  165409                 zygote
    0       39  165474                   gpu-process
    0       39  165410                 zygote
    0        0  165412                   zygote
    0       39  165472                 utility-network-service
    0        0  165486                 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/ps -ax -o pid=,ppid=,pcpu=,pmem=,command=
    0        0  165487                   /usr/bin/ps -ax -o pid=,ppid=,pcpu=,pmem=,command=
    0       39  165209       fileWatcher
    0      118  165138     extensionHost
    0       39  165208       /usr/share/code/code --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/json-language-features/server/dist/node/jsonServerMain --node-ipc --clientProcessId=165138
    0      157  165317       mono --assembly-loader=strict /home/one/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-linux-x64/.omnisharp/1.39.4/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe -z -s /home/one/github/ion/Migration/Migrator.sln --hostPID 165138 DotNet:enablePackageRestore=false --encoding utf-8 --loglevel information --plugin /home/one/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-linux-x64/.razor/OmniSharpPlugin/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.OmniSharpPlugin.dll FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:0=**/.git FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:1=**/.svn FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:2=**/.hg FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:3=**/CVS FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:4=**/.DS_Store FileOptions:SystemExcludeSearchPatterns:5=**/Thumbs.db FormattingOptions:EnableEditorConfigSupport=true formattingOptions:useTabs=false formattingOptions:tabSize=4 formattingOptions:indentationSize=4

Workspace Stats: 
|  Window (global.json - Migration - Visual Studio Code)
|    Folder (Migration): 82 files
|      File types: cs(32) json(9) md(9) csproj(2) bat(2) yml(2)
|                  gitattributes(1) gitignore(1) sln(1) cake(1)
|      Conf files: csproj(2) sln(1) dockerfile(1)
```

Comment: ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" is wrong. There isn't such thing as .NET Framework 6. Without seeing the contents of the .csproj file it's not possible to make further conclusions.

Comment: the csproj has `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: Could you please check what `code -s | grep dotnet` returns? Maybe you'll need to run VS Code first and then issue this command.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate a .NET Framework project to .NET Core? You can't just change the target version. The entire `csproj` format is completely different, the build tools are different. Try creating a new project in a new folder, eg a Console or Web API project, and edit it in VS Code. I suspect you won't have problems

Comment: Would be good to also post full csproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the version of CSharp extension (which uses OmniSharp) installed in your VS Code.

```bash
code --list-extensions --show-versions
```

And maybe more information can be obtained by running VS Code and then in parallel running the following command:

```bash
code -s | grep dotnet
```

Also what is returned by

```bash
dotnet --info
```

##### Update:

Setting `omnisharp.useModernNet` option to `true` resolved the issue.

Comment: Original post has been updated

Comment: Could you please also get the `code -s` output while running the VS Code with your project open?

Comment: The warning message from your original post contains `/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` so it looks like Mono is used instead of .NET SDK. I suspect it might be something with OmniSharp, that's why `code -s` output is desirable.

Comment: original post updated with new code -s output.

Comment: The process with PID 165317 is running under `mono`. I would expect it to run under `dotnet` to support .NET 6 SDK. I think it's controlled by `omnisharp.useModernNet` setting. Could you please check this setting and also try setting it to true to see if anything changes.

Comment: The main issue is the version of MSBuild used. The original post contains the path to it as `/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/`. So it would be interesting to find out which version is it. And how to change it to the right one.

Comment: omnisharp.useModernNet set to true fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is to use Rider instead of VSCode especially in ubuntu.
you can download it from

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Installation_guide.html

I got this error and i spent lots of time to fix it but never find the solution.

Comment: There is one major difference between the two - Rider is bot free.

Comment: I started to use Rider. It is much better than VS Code

Comment: You could also use the free version of Visual Studio - the Community Edition assuming you match the licencing criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I just run:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, uninstalled and reinstalled the extension in VS Code and it worked again.